# How can I write a form that assists my browser's auto-complete feature?

Tags: html, autocomplete, semantic-markup

How does Chrome, or other browsers, determine what data is appropriate to auto-complete into a particular form field?  Is it just based on the name and type?  Are there other semantic / microdata standards I should be aware of that can give it a hint?

I seem to recall reading a standard of form field hints for chrome, but I can't find that article anymore.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute):

> When the autofill field name is "`on`", the user agent should attempt to use heuristics to determine the most appropriate values to offer the user, e.g. based on the element's `name` value, the position of the element in the document's DOM, what other fields exist in the form, and so forth.

Several [**autofill field names**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#autofill-field) are defined, that can be used as values for the `autocomplete` attribute, for example:

- `name` for the full name
- `nickname` for the nickname, screen name, etc.
- `organization-title` for the job title
- `bday` for the birthday
- `tel` for the telephone number
- …

(FWIW, there is also [RFC 3106 which defines values for e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16736447/1591669).)

---

**Update (2015):** These *autofill field names* did **not** make it to the HTML5 REC. However, they are [again/still part of HTML 5.1 (WD)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140617/forms.html#autofill-field), and currently also [part of the Editor’s Draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#autofill-field).

**Update (2016):** It’s part of HTML 5.1 (REC): [Autofill](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#sec-autofill).

Answer (score 1):

### Microformats!

http://microformats.org/

They are open data formats based upon already existing standards.

vCard, hCard, etc!